# C# - Change format of Data received from Serial Port

Tags: c#, dataframe, serialization, serial-port

I am making a C# form application that receives data from an instrument communicating at Baud Rate 2400, parity None, 8 bit data, 1 stop bit.
The data is coming in a continuous string line in the form [000000][000000][000000]. For example if during a procedure the reading on the instrument is varying like 0.50,0.49,0.72,0.61,0.48 then the string of received data would be [000050][000049][000072][000061][000048], which is how it is currently being displayed in the textbox.

I need to display the Maximum value reached during a procedure into the textbox and in the correct format, like in this case it should be 0.72. I am at a loss about what would be the code for that.

Below is my current code for serial port communication.

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    
   //this is the button to open port.
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
            serialPort1.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    
    //Event handler for data received.
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[(\d+)\]");
        double.TryParse(richTextBox2.Text, out double max);
        foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(indata))
        {
            double val = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) / 100.0;
            if (val > max)
                max = val;
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = max.ToString();
    }
    


    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

    }

    //this is the button to close port
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : Port needs to be open or wrong port selected!");
        }
        
    }   


    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Close();
    }


    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        button2.Enabled = false;

    }
```

Comment: How is this `[000050][000049][000072][000061][000048]` represents a date? You might need to refer to the API programming manual of the instrument. There might be a meaning of each block, for example: `[000050]`

Comment: Presumably if you get a reading of 000356 that would be represented as 3.56? In other words, 2 numbers at the end represent the decimals and anything before those are tens, hundreds etc.

Comment: yes, two numbers at the end are after the decimal, rest first four represent units, tens, hundreds, thousands. This is a weighing scale. if it gives [123456] then it has to be read as 1234.56

Answer (score 1):

So you want to process data every time there is data to process right?

If you are using the "System.IO.Ports", and your serialPort1 is of the type SerialPort, you have the "DataReceived" event available. So after you instantiate the serialPort1 you can:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = true;
    try
    {
        //check and set the settings of your device
        serialPort1 = new SerialPort
        {
            PortName = comboBox1.Text,
            BaudRate = 2400,
            Parity = Parity.None,
            StopBits = StopBits.Odd,
            DataBits = 8,
            Handshake = Handshake.None,
            RtsEnable = true
        };

        serialPort1.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;
        serialPort1.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Then you just need to declare the event handler, something like this:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"\[(\d+)\]");
    double.TryParse(textBox13.Text, out double max);
    foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(indata))
    {
        double val = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) / 100.0;
        if (val > max)
            max = val;
    }
    textBox13.Text = max .ToString();
}
```

This will compare the values received and the current value in the textbox.

Comment: Its a neat solution, but part of the problem still remains. It is catching only momentary values when the button is clicked. As the values in the instrument rise and fall, for example ... 0.48, 0.30, 0.49, 0.50, 0.73, the program needs to be able to continuously keep changing the displayed value in textbox to the highest value reached in the string. One shouldn't need to click the button every time the value on instrument rises, and in any case its not possible to keep pace with the rapidly rising and falling values of the instrument. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have attempted this solution but the outcome is not different. I have edited my question to include all the codes related to Serial Communication so you can peruse. I tried calling the event handler through the receive button, and then I tried calling it in Main_Load and then in Form2_Load but to no different outcome. I have tried attempting a Loop but I concede my Loop Condition could be unfitting. Please take another look at this. Mind that the data is coming in a continuous string of horizontal line, not as vertical list.

Comment: @KshitijBali I am not completely sure of what is wrong but I have added the SerialPort creation to the answer and moved the "serialPort1.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;" to before opening the port.

Comment: @KshitijBali what actually happens when you try this solution? and what is different from your target? so we can better identify what to fix

Comment: Imagine a weighing scale. If one is to put pressure with a thumb on the weighing balance, then reading on instrument will increase until max pressure is reached, and then as one lifts the thumb the pressure on the balance would drop and also the readings. Obj. is that rise in readings from 0.00 to say 1.17 should be visible in TextBox as its visible on instrument, but say if 1.17 is the highest reached then 1.17 should be frozen on display even when readings drop. It shouldn't change unless higher pressure than 1.17 is applied or if the button (which doubles as a refresh) is clicked again.

Comment: Button should be clicked only when beginning the experiment or when refreshing. After clicking it should show the changing readings if the readings are on a rise, but if they fall then it should freeze the display to the highest value reached unless the readings begin to rise again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you're formatting requirement correctly you basically want to remove zeros at the front from each of the numbers and then compare them to find the max value and display them in the format of x.xx If that's the case create a separate method to handle it like this:

```
    private decimal GetMaxReading(string rawReadingData)
    {
        decimal maxReading = 0;
        var readings = rawReadingData.Split('[',).ToList();

        foreach (var reading in readings)
        {
            var readingString = reading.TrimStart('0')
                                       .TrimEnd(']');

            var isInt = int.TryParse(readingString, out int readingValue);
            var value = isInt ? (decimal)readingValue / 100 : 0;
            maxReading = value > maxReading ? value : maxReading;
        }

        return maxReading;
    }
```